# What is the primary key and candidate key in this relationship?

Tags: database, database-schema, rdbms

given this relation what would the primary key and two candidate keys be?

Computer-Surgery: {Customer-name (Customer-Firstname, Customer-Lastname), Customer-Email, Customer-Tel, Customer-Address (House-No/Name, Post-Code, City, County, Country), Customer-Age, Customer-Feedback, Customer-Feedback-Score, Customer-Type, Request-Date/time, Authorised-by, staff-name(Staff-Firstname, staff-Lastname), staff-Email, {staff-Qualifications}, Service-Type, Service-Description, Service-Name, Service-Price, Discount, Served-Price, Served-Location, Served-Date/Time, Total-Price}

Service name is a short name for your service ex. Installing antivirus
Service description is a full description to your service ex. Installing antivirus includes scanning your machine and removing any virus and be sure its clean and the antivirus is working well.
Service type might be hardware, software, maintenance, etc…
Service price is the prices on your service table against your services; this could be changed at any time 
Served price is the price that you agreed on with a customer this should not be changed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: No, reading through it I realize it does sound like that but it isn't

Comment: knowing nothing about this data, a good candidate would be email, since email is unique. Unless, you have more than one customer per email, then you'd need to add another column, like name. Some DBs allow multi-column PKs (composite), some don't.

Is there any way you  can add a new column with a sequence of numbers and use that as a PK?

Comment: Explain how you are using parentheses & curly braces. CKs are determined from functional dependencies. What are yours? What have you got so far? What reference are you using? PS What is a "service ex"?

Answer (score 0):

FIrst, this is clearly not a homework question since I trust nobody would come up with such a bad design for a homework question.  It may be 1NF but is clearly not 2NF since you have a lot of data dependent on pieces of the candidate keys.  Since this is a piece of software, first advice is normalize this relation to at least 3NF.

I think your primary key is going to have to be (customer_email, staff_email, service_type, served_datetime).  I see no other candidate keys.  And this should be broken into at least four tables.